# How to force indentation in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I'm using the Community Edition of Intellij IDEA. I'm a little annoyed at how it restricts the way I use indentation in some areas. For example, it's hard to format the multi-line String below using tab key:

```
def text = """
This is a multi-line comment.
    I want this indented.
    And this too.
"""
```

I've been looking at the code style options but I can't figure out which one to configure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any configuration for multi line strings. I guess formatting the contents of Strings is in itself a bit dangerous. I expect auto format to change the *format* of my code, not the *semantics* of my code.

The following might ease your pain a bit if you find yourself doing custom formatting not supported by auto format:

1. Turn on Markers for turning on and off formatters. This allows you to specify comments that will define areas of your code that auto format won't touch. Look for the checkboxes in Editor -> Code Style under "Formatter Control"
2. If you mark multiple lines and press [TAB], IntelliJ will indent all of lines.

Comment: I found out that it doesn't even have to be multiple lines; tabbing works even if there's only one line of code highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your string without indentations and then use multi line edit (multi cursor) to indent all the lines you want at the same time.

More on that feature in the link below (and also a short video demo):
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/